# crontab's @reboot only works for root?

Tags: cron, reboot

`man 5 crontab` is pretty clear on how to use crontab to run a script on boot:

```
   These special time specification "nicknames" are supported, which replace the 5 initial time and date
   fields, and are prefixed by the `@` character:
   @reboot    :    Run once after reboot.
```

So I happily added a single line to my crontab (under my user account, not root):

```
@reboot     /home/me/myscript.sh
```

But for some reason, myscript.sh wouldn't run on machine reboot.
(it runs fine if I invoke it from the command line, so it's not a permissions problem)

What am I missing?

---

Update to answer @Anthon's questions:

1. Oracle-linux version: 5.8 (uname: 2.6.32-300.39.2.el5uek #1 SMP)
2. Cron version: vixie-cron-4.1-81.el5.x86_64
3. Yes, `/home` **is** a mounted partition. Looks like this is the problem. How do I workaround this?
4. Currently, `myscript.sh` only echos a text message to a file in `/home/me`.

Comment: your user crontab does not support @reboot option, there are a few crontab layouts, once you start poking around.

Comment: @XTian Thanks. What is the recommended way to run a script on reboot as a user other than root?

Comment: I would put an entry in the user's environment when they login, or add a line to `/etc/rc.local`. `su - <user> -c "run your command here"`.

Comment: What you are missing is unclear, but what we are missing is details. What version of oracle-linux are you running? Which version of cron do you have? Is `/home` a mounted partition? What are the contents of your `/home/me/myscript.sh`?

Comment: Oracle Linux derives from RHEL. I believe there have only been releases of it for 4, 5, and 6. Testing `@reboot` in CentOS is likely a good test for confirming if it will work in Oracle's Linux.

Comment: If you're using Oracle's Lin. ver. 5 there is this changelog about issues with vixie-cron + `@reboot`. https://oss.oracle.com/pipermail/el-errata/2012-March/002655.html

Comment: Would it not run, or would it not get started? Can you provide details on the script. I use this so I know it to work for sure.

Comment: @slm My vixie-cron version (see OP update above) is exactly the one referred to in your link as the one that resolves the `@reboot` problem... I am confused.

Comment: @Daniel - is `myscript.sh` executable? `chmod +x myscript.sh`.

Comment: @slm, Yes it is executable. I think I found the culprit (just as Anthon originally suggested, see my comment to him below). I am going to try now your `/etc/rc.local. su - <user> -c ` suggestion.

Comment: @Daniel - I've added another tip on debugging cron to my answer which might help as well.

Comment: Is your home directory encrypted?  Can you try running a different command not involving your home directory like     `@reboot touch /tmp/me.txt > /tmp/trouble.txt 2>&1`

Comment: In Debian 8 "Jessie" in `/etc/crontab` seems there is a requirement to specify a user after `@reboot`. In most cases it is `root`. Otherwise the command may not work at all and `cron` throw an error in `syslog`.

Comment: It may also be a problem with the `$PATH`.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

This can be a bit of a confusing topic because there are different implementations of cron. Also there were several bugs that broke this feature, and there are also some use cases where it simply won't work, specifically if you do a shutdown/boot vs. a reboot.

#### Bugs

*datapoint #1*

One such bug in Debian is covered here, titled: [cron: @reboot jobs are not run](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=635473). This seems to have made it's way into Ubuntu as well, which I can't confirm directly.

*datapoint #2*

Evidence of the bug in Ubuntu would seem to be confirmed here in this SO Q&A titled: [@reboot cronjob not executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18158427/reboot-cronjob-not-executing).

*excerpt*

> comment #1: .... 3) your version of crond may not support @reboot are you using vix's crond? ... show results of crontab -l -u user
>
> comment #2: ... It might be a good idea to set it up as an init script instead of relying on a specific version of cron's @reboot.
>
> comment #3: ... @MarkRoberts removed the reboot and modified the 1 * * * * , to */1 * * * * , problem is solved! Where do I send the rep pts Mark? Thank you!

The accepted answer in that Q&A also had this comment:

> Seems to me Lubuntu doesn't support the @Reboot Cron syntax.

#### Additional evidence

*datapoint #3*

As additional evidence there was this thread that someone was attempting the very same thing and getting frustrated that it didn't work. It's titled: [Thread: Cron - @reboot jobs not working](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1530652).

*excerpt*

> Re: Cron - @reboot jobs not working
>
> > Quote Originally Posted by ceallred  View Post
> >     This is killing me... Tried the wrapper script. Running manually generates the log file... rebooting and the job doesn't run or create log file.
> >
> > Syslog shows that CRON ran the job... but again, no output and the process isn't running.
> >     Jul 15 20:07:45 RavenWing cron[1026]: (CRON) INFO (Running @reboot jobs)
> >     Jul 15 20:07:45 RavenWing CRON[1053]: (ceallred) CMD (/home/ceallred/Scripts/run_spideroak.sh > /home/ceallred/Scripts/SpiderOak.log 2>&1 &)
> >
> > It's seems like cron doesn't like the @reboot command.... Any other ideas?
>
> Okay... Partially solved. I'll mark this one as solved and start a new thread with the new issue.....
>
> I think the answer was my encrypted home directory wasn't mounted when CRON was trying to run the script (stored in /home/username/scripts). Moved to /usr/scripts and the job runs as expected.
>
> So now it appears to be a spideroak issue. Process starts, but by the time the boot process is finished, it's gone. I'm guessing a crash for some reason.... New thread to ask about that.
>
> Thanks for all the help!

Once this above user figured out his issue he was able to get `@reboot` working out of the crontab entry of a user.

I'm not entirely sure what version of cron is used on Ubuntu, but this would seem to indicate that user's can use `@reboot` too, or that the bug was fixed at some point in subsequent versions of cron.

*datapoint #4*

I tested on CentOS 6 the following and it worked.

#### Example

```
$ crontab -l
@reboot echo "hi" > /home/sam/reboot.txt 2>&1
```

I then rebooted the system.

```
$ sudo reboot
```

After the reboot.

```
$ cat reboot.txt 
hi
```

#### Take aways

1. This feature does seem to be supported for both system and user crontab entries.
2. You have to make sure that it's supported/working in your particular distro and/or version of the cron package.

For more on how the actual mechanism works for `@reboot` I did come across this blog post which discusses the innards. It's titled: [@reboot - explaining simple cron magic](http://www.unixdaemon.net/linux/how-does-cron-reboot-work.html).

#### Debugging crond

You can turn up the verbosity of `crond` by adding the following to this configuration file on RHEL/CentOS/Fedora based distros.

```
$ more crond 
# Settings for the CRON daemon.
# CRONDARGS= :  any extra command-line startup arguments for crond
CRONDARGS="-L 2"
```

The valid levels are 0, 1, or 2. To revert this file back to it's default logging level simply remove the `"-L 2"` when you're done debugging the situation.

Comment: Got a [comment](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/79179/running-a-daemon-as-a-non-privileged-user/79182?noredirect=1#comment169590_79182) yesterday, looked at your answer and decided to answer myself after a good night sleep. Set up a VM, retried @reboot, wanted to post my answer and only then saw you 'reworded' your answer :-(

Comment: @Anthon - sorry, I quickly answered it yesterday and then continued to research it and found very conflicting details. When I found the bug on Debian about it and Ubuntu SO I realized some of what was at play. I saw that it worked on CentOS and put it together that `@reboot` is OK in certain crons, and apparently buggy/broken in others. Hence the confusion.

Comment: Apart from that the OP provides little detail, you can easily use something that does not work yet (at boot time) in your script that make it fail, or have it reside on a not-yet-mounted disc. My answer which the OP commented on, was confirmed by a 3rd party as well. It is the black swan problem...

Comment: @Anthon - yes one of my datapoints was exactly that. `@reboot` worked once you realized it was trying to access an encrypted drive, that hadn't been mounted as of yet.

Comment: You might want to point out that the bug in Ubuntu is easily solved by adding a delay: `@reboot sleep 60; <your command>`. To quote the thread, "my guess is that cron's @reboot directive is running too early in the boot process"

Answer (score 26):

I found out that on my Ubuntu machine, I do not have access to dns services, yet, at @reboot time. This prevented me from mounting remote volumes. This corny, yet simple, solution worked:

`@reboot sleep 60 && /home/me/bin/mount.sh 2>&1 >> /home/me/reboot.log`

(in root cron; last parts only for debugging)

Comment: This is the only thing that actually works on ubuntu 16.04 for non-root users!

Comment: Not working on Debian 8 jessie (gnome 3). :(

Comment: This worked for me when dealing with mounting VMWare shared folders to a separate location.

Answer (score 4):

I have mac osx as well and I had same issue where my script were not running. but When i fixed my script to like

```
@reboot   cd /home/me/  && sh myscript.sh
```

it worked fine for me. make sure to make your shell file to be executable by running the command

```
chmod +x myscript.sh
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if you have already solved this, or if any of the above was the solution you needed, but another possibility is:

if you have your /home directory encrypted, it may not be available until you log in, i.e. it is not available at reboot.

in this scenario, you could move your scripts to another location like /srv or /opt or /usr/local/bin/ etc.

Answer (score 1):

Take a fresh install of Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 (default user in my case: avanderneut).

```
avanderneut@uggo:~$ crontab -l
no crontab for avanderneut
avanderneut@uggo:~$ crontab -e
no crontab for avanderneut - using an empty one

Select an editor.  To change later, run 'select-editor'.
  1. /bin/ed
  2. /bin/nano        <---- easiest
  3. /usr/bin/vim.tiny

Choose 1-3 [2]: 3
crontab: installing new crontab
avanderneut@uggo:~$ crontab -l | tail -2
# m h  dom mon dow   command
@reboot /home/avanderneut/bin/on_reboot
avanderneut@uggo:~$ vi /home/avanderneut/bin/on_reboot
avanderneut@uggo:~$ more !$
more /home/avanderneut/bin/on_reboot
#! /bin/bash
echo "Reboot script" > /var/tmp/xxx
avanderneut@uggo:~$ chmod 755 /home/avanderneut/bin/on_reboot
avanderneut@uggo:~$ ls /var/tmp
avanderneut@uggo:~$ /home/avanderneut/bin/on_reboot
avanderneut@uggo:~$ ls /var/tmp
xxx
avanderneut@uggo:~$ rm /var/tmp/xxx
avanderneut@uggo:~$ sudo reboot
[sudo] password for avanderneut:
```

And see that after reboot the file `/var/tmp/xxx` is there **although** it was not there before rebooting.

This was done with cron version 3.0.

You have to make sure that no services discs etc are used that might not be available at the time the script runs. Start with something simple like the above and make sure it has no terminal output as email is probably not up and running.

You might aslo need a more up-to-date cron (or an upgrade from oracle-linux) if this did not work for you and you need this feature.

Comment: I updated my OP to answer your questions. Turns out your suspicion was right from the start: The script to-be-run on reboot resides on a mountable `/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-LogVol01` partition.

Comment: @Daniel Thanks for letting me know, I'm glad you found the culprit. I am not sure if you can delay the start of cron until the partitions are mounted, some of that startup is done in parallel and you would have to change dependencies. I would not want to mess with that and possible break `cron`. You should IMHO take a different route than crontab & @reboot to run something once on startup as the user.

Answer (score 0):

I would say yes for the question. Just had difficulties with running cron on reboot (Debian 3.10.70) and managed to solve with:

`@reboot root /usr/bin/python3 /path/to/script`

And a newline character  **'\n'** in the end

This is the contents of file:

```
/etc/cron.d/runOnReboot
```

Finally, I think it is worth noting an abstract from `man 5 crontab`

> ...
>   The format of a cron command is very much the V7 standard, with a number of upward-compatible extensions.   Each  line  has  five  time  and  date
>          fields,  followed  by  a command, followed by a newline character ('\n').  The system crontab (/etc/crontab) uses the same format, except that the
>          username for the command is specified after the time and date fields and before the command. The fields may be separated by spaces  or  tabs.  The
>          maximum permitted length for the command field is 998 characters.
>   ...

Answer (score 0):

I use as below

```
export EDITOR=gedit && sudo crontab -e
@reboot /home/usuario/script.sh
```

Answer (score -1):

First of all, you should login as root:

> sudo -i

Then open crontab:

> crontab -e

After that, add your script to crontab as root like below:

> @reboot root /home/user1/Desktop/my_script

As a result I saw that my script work right.

Note: If you edit crontab with your current user, the reboot cannot call your script properly.

Answer (score -3):

prueba:

usuario@ubuntu:~$ touch script.sh
usuario@ubuntu:~$ chmod +x script.sh

usuario@ubuntu:~$ $crontrab -e

@reboot /home/usuario/script.sh

save and restart your pc