# Run jar on startup in all *nix based systems

Tags: linux, shell, shell-script, java, startup

I have a jar file which I need to run at startup in all distros of Linux. My previous question [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131503/run-a-script-at-startup), gave me an idea a rough idea on X-servers. Since I wasn't able to perform startup, I moved on to the idea of adding a .desktop file to `/etc/xdg/autostart`. This works for ubuntu and I am currently testing it in Linux Mint both cinnamon and mate versions. I did a small research for other distros but they don't seem to have the `/etc/xdg/autostart` instead they have `/xdg-autostart` but I need to run my jar file in all distros of Linux. I tried crontab but `@reboot` didn't work in ubuntu 14.04 for me. Another problem is I need to remove the file I am placing to startup when I uninstall the jar. If I edit rc.local, I won't be able to revert the edit. Is there a common way in which I can do startup in Linux

Comment: The XDG autostart (X server based) mechanism is fundamentally different from the `rc.local` (init based) one.  The former starts applications inside *per user* GUI sessions.  The latter starts things on a system wide basis, and is not appropriate for GUI applications since GUI sessions are instantiated per logged in user.  You need to differentiate and explain which of those two possibilities you want to exploit.

Comment: @goldilocks My jar file works without UI but at times when server sends message, a window will be opened with the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no universal method for creating a system service on all GNU/Linux distros, since they use a variety of init systems.  Once upon a time they all used more or less the same [SysV style init](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SysV_init#SysV-style) (excepting some which used a more BSD style system), which allowed for the writing of generic init scripts that would require little modification from distro to distro.

Currently, SysV is still used by a number of distros, such as Debian and RHEL / CentOS.  However, the newer init systems -- [systemd](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemd) (Fedora, Arch, et. al.) and [upstart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upstart) (Ubuntu)<sup>1</sup> do include mechanisms for backward support of SysV style init scrips, so if you are looking for the method most easily adopted for use on the most systems, that is still it.

Keep in mind that "linux" is not an operating system in the sense that "Windows 8" or "OSX" are operating systems.  *Linux* is an OS kernel used on a wide variety of platforms (e.g., Android); colloquially "GNU/Linux" refers to the collection of OS distributions discussed above, but these *are not* all the same.  There is no serious intention or desire to unify these, just as there is no serious intention or desire to unify Windows and OSX so that, e.g., someone could ask "How can I run my jar file at start up on both OSX and Windows?" -- you are out of luck, you will need to package it separately for each of them.  That is, in fact, how software in the linux world generally is distributed; there are *separate packages* for each and every distro.

<sup>1 *BUT* Ubuntu (and Debian) are [moving to systemd](http://www.markshuttleworth.com/archives/1316), meaning upstart will likely disappear, and most of the major distros will have a common init system.</sup>

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Is there a way where I can identify the init systems in the distro using java and write a script accordingly? Because on running my jar file I need it to write the script and set to the respective area. If I am installing my jar file in say 500 systems, I cannot manually write a script in every system. If I find the init system and write the script, it would be a easier task.

Comment: I would not put everything in the jar or do the install using java; use a `tar`red package with a separate install script (i.e, the normative approach -- also this way the jar will be the same even if the install method differs).  Vis. identifying the init system, that would be a good separate question of its own BUT I think if you really need to install to 500 machines, you should first find out what those machines are running and create a few different packages to cover them.  When you hit a case that isn't covered, deal with it; you may end up with 3 or 4 different versions...

Comment: ...of the installer.  Don't try to cover all (theoretical) situations.  Start with actual ones.

Comment: I will try and suggest the `tar` package. But how can we determine where the script should be located when we use it? and as for the distros, I think mostly Ubuntu, Mint, Redhat and CentOS will be used. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: What I'm saying is don't bother with one package that detects the system, at least not for now.  Come up with something that works on ubuntu, then test it on mint (I think they both use upstart, if you are going to use init).  If that works, you have an upstart (or whatever) oriented package for use on systems that work that way.  Someone has to arrange the actual install, so they can decide which package to use where.

Comment: As I said, I already have `/etc/xdg/autostart` method in `Ubuntu`. I am actually trying to test in `Mint` now. Can you provide me some good links on `tar` packaging and `systemd`, so that I can research more on these?

Comment: I just use the `man` pages, but if you look around you should be able to find some tutorials.  Arch uses systemd and generally has [a great wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Systemd).  However, **note that using the init system (e.g. upstart, systemd) and using xdg are fundamentally different** as explained in my first comment on your question!  You probably want to stick to the same method on all systems...

Comment: Ya. I got the difference from your first comment. I will try to research on init systems but for some knowledge I am trying to implement `xdg` in `Mint`.

Answer (score 4):

Regrettably, I don't believe there is a single, universal way to accomplish exactly what you want. Each nix has an init system, and there are various different init systems out there (SysV, Upstart, systemd, etc.). Now, systemd has *some* support for running SysV daemons, so you might be able to get away with writing a SysV script and have it work for both, but I do not know how that will fare with Upstart and other systems. I can see two courses of action that may yet help you accomplish your goal:

1. Write a service for each major init system (note that many distros are switching to systemd, so it may be a good one to start with).
2. Give up on running it at boot and try to run it a little later.

For example, though init systems are still pretty fragmented, shell login is pretty much universal. You could add a couple lines to each `$HOME/.shellrc` running the jar if it hasn't already been run. Doing so would be much less work and much more universally applicable.

The obvious advantage of `1` is that it would run the jar before users see anything. However, this can be mitigated in `2` by setting up autologin (though not a great idea for security).

Note that, if this is a GUI jar, then you're going to have a fair number of extra headaches (making X, or Wayland start so that your jar can run will add a few lines, at least, to whatever solution you decide).

Comment: My jar is a background process but when the server sends a message, a `JOptionPane message dialog` will be displayed. Case 1: I should be able to find the  init system used via java. Is it possible to find it via java or terminal? Case 2: I need the jar to run on startup automatically but an delay around 10 sec is acceptable. Even for that we will be writing a script to activate the jar right? `$HOME/.shellrc` isn't common to all distros. To my knowledge, shell can be bash or sh. I am a beginner so correct me if I am wrong. I need to find the shell and script accordingly right?

Comment: +1 There is no universal system.  My advice would be: if you want to run a system wide service, start with one distro, or one init system, work it out there, and then consider the others.

Comment: @goldilocks I already tried it in `ubuntu`. I first tried `crontab` but `@reboot` did not work for me. So I switched to `rc.local` but the problem is I won't be able to remove the edited line using java while uninstalling the jar. So I searched some more and got to adding a `.desktop` file to `/etc/xdg/autostart`. This method was easy for me, as I can remove the `.desktop` files and script from `/usr/bin` during unistallation