# Not all shell scripts working with crontab

Tags: cron

I have a little VPS I run apache and a Minecraft server on. I don't ever turn it off, but should I restart it for some reason, IPTables blocks most of my ports, including port 80. I've tried so many different suggestions on fixing this, but with no luck. Also, since the provider is OVH, the support is... lacking.

So, I've created a workaround, which I'm happy with. I created a simple shell script file to open certain ports I need opened on restart (80 and 25565 for now). The important ones such as 21 and 22 are not affected on restart.

The script looks like this:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --dport 25565 -j ACCEPT
/sbin/service iptables save
```

When I manually run it by typing `/iptdef.sh`, it runs fine, the ports become open and it's all good.

Of course, it's not practical having to remember to run it every time I restart the server, so I added a crontab. The problem is, it doesn't work/run. This is my crontab file:

```
*/5 * * * * /backup2.sh
*/55 * * * * /backup3.sh
@reboot /iptdef.sh
* * * * *  /iptdef.sh
```

The first two lines work. They are just simple scripts that make a backup of a folder for me. The second two lines are what's not working.

Is there a chance that perhaps it's not possible to run iptables commands from a cron? It sounds silly, but I can't see any other reason for it not to work. The scripts have the correct permissions.

Comment: Are the scripts being run as root (basically, are they in `root`'s crontab)?

Comment: Yes, it is. I even tried giving the script public execution permissions, just in case, but nope, still the same old nothingness.

Comment: WAIT A SECOND I THINK I FOUND THE PROBLEM

Comment: Or not - I just realised I missed off the all important `#!/bin/bash` line at the top of the `iptdef.sh` file, so I added it, yet still no luck. Give up time soon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because cron forcibly sets `PATH` to `/usr/bin:/bin`.  You need to invoke `iptables` as `/sbin/iptables` or add `PATH=/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin` in your script or crontab.  See crontab(5) for details.

Comment: I added `PATH=/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/bin` to top of the script file and it works perfectly!
You, sir, are a gentleman and a scholar and a breeder of fine horses!

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it is covered well here: [crontab's @reboot only works for root?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/109804/crontabs-reboot-only-works-for-root) basically the answer depends heavily on what you use for Cron and your Linux distribution.

Comment: The issue isn't just that. As you can see, it's also supposed to run every minute too (although it's also running as root anyway)

Answer (score 0):

I had to add this to `/etc/hosts` so that mail to anyone at my server's own FQDN  would be resolved:

`127.0.0.1   mydomain.com.`

Notice the dot at the end.  In my case, I'm sending email essentially to root@localhost with `MAILTO=root` which gets translated to root@mydomain.com.

[Here's some more detail on this answer.](https://serverfault.com/questions/115790/mailto-is-not-working-for-cron-how-can-i-fix-this/869007#869007)