# Loading netplan scripts from optional mount target

Tags: systemd, systemd-networkd, netplan

I'm trying to leverage netplan's ability to override configurations with lexicographically later files, but when these files come from another mount point, the whole thing fails.

I've created a virtual machine with a few interfaces, and those are configured with sensible defaults using files like `/etc/netplan/01-primary.yaml` and `/etc/netplan/02-local.yaml` (which basically say "use dhcp"). That part works well. However what I'm trying to achieve is the ability to override the settings using an *optional* drive mount.

For this I have added a mount point to `/etc/fstab` with the following contents:

```
/dev/vdb /mnt/config ext4 defaults,nofail,x-systemd.device-timeout=10,x-systemd.before=systemd-networkd.service 0 0
```

And then I added symlinks to `/etc/netplan` that point to new config files, such as `ln -s /mnt/config/netplan/11-primary.yaml /etc/netplan/11-primary.yaml`.

My first problem was that if the drive is not present and mounted, the whole netplan generate fails at boot time and I am left without any interfaces (I have issued a [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/netplan/+bug/1788360) about missing symlinks to netplan). I managed to overcome this issue by simply creating the necessary directory structure with empty files in `/mnt/config`. However even with the drive present, netplan does not see these files at boot time. If I run `netplan generate` and `netplan apply` after boot, all the interfaces  get configured correctly.

I have tried many different `x-systemd.before` targets but none of them work. Is there any way to get this working correctly? The config mount should be optional so that the virtual machine can be booted without one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have been struggling with this today and I've identified two main solutions for it so far:

1. Use cron to run `netplan apply` on `@reboot` but there seemed to be way [too many caveats](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/109805/188832) attached to it.
2. Create a systemd unit to run `netplan apply` after the mount.

I choose option 2 and here is the systemd unit file:

```
[Unit]
Description=Execute netplan apply after mount
After=multi-user.target mnt.mount

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c "netplan apply"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Save it under `/etc/systemd/system/network-after-mount.service` and go `systemctl enable network-after-mount`. Reboot to test.

In our case it's an internal USB stick which gets mounted under `/mnt/` containing the extra netplan config files. If you mount your drive under another path the generated systemd mount unit will be named differently. You can list the mount units with

```
systemctl list-units --type=mount
```

and identify which is the correct one to target.

Comment: This additional service sounds like it might work, as long as all other dependencies are in place. I too tried using the `@reboot` cron, but as there are other services that are dependent on network, this was not a very good idea. I will try and see if the additional `service` might do the trick. Thanks!